# Optimal presentation of a two-row table

Tags: tables

My question is about the aesthetics of a certain table and as such is opinion-based and likely to be closed. I am wondering what's the optimal presentation of the following table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
c r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r      
%S[table-format= 1.0]
}
\toprule 
$n$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$ & $10$ 
& $11$ & $12$ & $13$ & $14$ & $15$ & $16$ & $17$ & $18$ 
\\
\midrule
$\mu(n)$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $0$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ 
& $-1$ & $0$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & $-1$ & $0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: "optimal presentation" definitely is at least somewhat opinion-based, but if you already have a certain improvement in mind, there most likely is a way to implement it. Apart from that: are you aware that your table currently is wider than the textwidth?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using the fullpage package. What I am wondering about is how to handle the different space-lengths that minus signs introduce.

Comment: So your actual question is "how to make all columns equally wide"?

Comment: Not necessarily. My question *really* is: what would an experienced user do here? (I understand it's not a good question to ask.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such a wide table I'd make it as wide as possible, using `tabular*`. Columns beside the first can be given the same width with `w{c}{1em}`. I've added nonsense words to show the table in context.

This exploits the fact that the last column has no minus sign, otherwise the common width should be a tad longer. You can measure the width with several methods, in case you need it.

The mid rule has been made very thin. I also made `\belowcaptionskip` to be modified in *every* table, and also `\abovecaptionskip` set to zero.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\AddToHook{env/table/begin}{%
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\medskipamount}%
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$

\begin{table}[htp] % <-- don't forget p
\centering

\caption{Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}

% a local assignment to get easier input
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}w{c}{1em}<{$}}
% remove the intercolumn spaces
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{$}c<{$}
  *{18}{C}
  @{}
}
\toprule 
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 
& 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 
\\
\midrule[0.1pt]
\mu(n) & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
& -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$
Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a `tabularx` package, to assure that the 18 numerical columns all have the exact same width, irrespective of the number of digits in the numbers in the upper row or the presence or absence of a minus symbol in the second row.

I'd also omit `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` in order to simplify and streamline the visual presentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel} % optional
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif} % choose a font that features the requisite glyphs
\usepackage{fullpage,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}X<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l r *{17}{R} @{}}
%\toprule 
$n$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 
\\
\midrule
$\mu(n)$ & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Some alternative approaches using `array` or `siunitx` in order to simplify the code.

[image]

(Red lines indicate text block/margins)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Caption text}
\centering
\[\begin{array}{l *{18}{wr{3ex}} }
\toprule 
n      & 1 & 2  & 3  & 4 & 5  & 6 & 7  & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \midrule
\mu(n) & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & 1  & 0  & -1 & 0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{array}\]
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Caption text}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$} *{18}{S[table-format=-1]}@{}}
\toprule 
n      & 1 & 2  & 3  & 4 & 5  & 6 & 7  & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \midrule
\mu(n) & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & 1  & 0  & -1 & 0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Caption text}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{$}l<{$} *{18}{S[table-format=-1]} }
\toprule 
n      & 1 & 2  & 3  & 4 & 5  & 6 & 7  & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \midrule
\mu(n) & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & 1  & 0  & -1 & 0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Caption text}
\[\begin{array}{l *{9}{r} }
\toprule 
n      & 1   & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  \\ \midrule
\mu(n) & 1   & -1 & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & -1 & 0  & 0  \\ \bottomrule \addlinespace \toprule
n      &  10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \midrule
\mu(n) & 1   & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & 1  & 0  & -1 & 0  \\ \bottomrule
\end{array}\]
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the extra space the minus signs are introducing is bothering you, you could use `\mathllap` (from `mathtools`), like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{M\"obius function $\mu$}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
c r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r r      
%S[table-format= 1.0]
}
\toprule 
$n$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$ & $10$ 
& $11$ & $12$ & $13$ & $14$ & $15$ & $16$ & $17$ & $18$ 
\\
\midrule
$\mu(n)$ & $1$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $0$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $1$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ 
& $\mathllap{-1}$ & $0$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & $\mathllap{-1}$ & $0$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{Table:MobiusFunction}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Whether this is an improvement (much less optimal) is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Thanks. It does look better this way. I'll wait a little before accepting.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not competing for "optimal", but the three-valued nature of the table suggested that a line, or in this case, an area plot might ease the visual perception of the data:

[image: two-rowed value table of the moebius function for values n=1 to 18]

Maybe a more subtle approach which only would extend the horizontal line upwards or downwards might do the same without completely ruining the tabular structure...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\h}{\cellcolor{black}\color{white}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}X<{$}}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering        
        \caption{Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$}
        \label{tab:moebius}
               
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{18}{R} @{}}
            $n$ & 
            \h 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 
            \h 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
            \h 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 &
            \h 14 &
            \h 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
            \hline
            $\mu(n)$ & 1 & 
            \h -1 & 
            \h -1 & 0 & 
            \h -1 & 1 & 
            \h -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 
            \h -1 & 0 & 
            \h -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 
            \h -1 & 0  \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

#### Second iteration

Frame challenge: the best presentation of this two-row table might be three rows:

[image: three-rowed value table of the moebius function for values n=1 to 18]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\h}{\cellcolor{black!10}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering        
        \caption{Οι αρχικές τιμές της συνάρτησης $\mu$}
        \label{tab:moebius}
               
        \begin{tabular}{l *{18}{P{1em}}} \toprule
            $\mu(n) = \phantom{-{}} 1$ & \h 1 &      &   &     &   & \h6 &   &   &   & \h10 &    &    &    & \h14 & \h15 &    &    &    \\ 
            $\mu(n) = \phantom{-{}} 0 ~$ &      &      &   & \h4 &   &   &   & \h8 & \h9 &    &    & \h12 &    &    &    & \h16 &    & \h18  \\ 
            $\mu(n) =-1$ &      & \h 2 & \h3     &   & \h5 &   & \h7 &   &   &    & \h 11 &    & \h 13 &    &    &    & \h 17 &    \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```